# unicode character passing from java to xml

Tags: java, xml

&#145 is a unicode character which has to be passed to xml from java, so that the special character is displayed on the page. But, instead of special character, &#145 is displayed as it is on the page. I tried using escape sequence but of no help. Please help in this context.

Comment: We'll need more info regarding how you build the XML. Do you use DOM? JDOM? The StAX API? Are there XSLT transformations involved? What exactly do you mean when you say "&#145 is displayed as it is on the page"? You mean the actual ampersand, hash and number sequence is shown? If you're manually outputting this, see if you didn't omit the semicolon at the end (should be `&#145;`).

Answer (score 0):

`&#145` is not a Unicode character. It looks a lot like a [numeric character reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) but it's incomplete without the terminating `;`. Try `&#145;` to see if that fixes your problem.

If that doesn't work: Not all XML parsers convert numeric character references to Unicode by default. See the documentation for the options to enable/configure character entity processing.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (or rather, I guess, because you've left us with no choice but to guess) that you are passing the character string & # 1 4 5 to some API that expects a string value. That isn't going to be unescaped unless the interface is one that expects to be passed XML, and to parse the XML. Instead, just pass a string containing this character without escaping.